# sailsJs, error using two controllers

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails.io.js

In sails.Js, how can i use a controller with two models?

like, in my page a have a reference `<%= user.city%>`, 
in another model, i have a list like:

`{
   street
},
{
  state
},
{
 house
}`

how can i do, to use `<%= user.city.street%>` in my page?

Info: i have two models, "User" and "Info",   the list is in the info model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you associate model "Info" in "User"?

Model **User**

```
city: {
            model: "Info"
        },
```

Now then populate city in controller,

```
User.find().populate('city').exec(function(err,users){res.view(users);});
```

so you can use `<%= user.city.street%>`

Comment: i've tried, but when i use populate('city'), i get an Error: Encountered unexpected error while building join instructions for `.populate("city")`, i've tried method populateAll, but it not works too.
  Details:
[Error: In `.populate("city")`, attempting to populate an attribute that doesn't exist]

Comment: Have you have put city attribute in Model User.js and then associated with city?

Comment: Are you storing street,state,house,etc in info model and  try to populate it through city attribute in user model? If then .. I would say that as you are storing location information(street,state,house) in info you can make location model to store (street, state, house) and then associate it in user model by `location:{model:"Location"}`, and then populate it as `User.find().populate('location')`...  Hope it help you.

Comment: yes, i tried an alternative method, ive changed my controller `function from User.findOne(req.param('id')).populateAll().exec( function foundUser(err, user){` 
 
      ,     to
`User.findOne(req.param('id')).populateAll().exec( function foundUser(err, user) {
 Info.findOne(req.param('id')).populateAll().exec( function foundCity(err, city) {
   res.view({
      user: user
      city: city
});
}`

Comment: everything is working, fine, your answer helpme so much, now i just wanna to know : this method is a valid option? or it will cause an error in my project?

Comment: Right now you are using OneWayAssociation. city is directly associated with user. So populate it to get associated model(here. city model in user model like. `user.city`). And if id of user and info do not match it will cause error. In my view  if you are saving id of info model in user model, then it should be valid.

Comment: ehr, how can i populate and render a view sometime?,
 how to populate this code: `User.find(function foundUsers(err, users) {
res.view({
      users: users
    });
 };`
 i need to populate the `location` model, that your has said

Comment: Are you setting attribute like `locationId: {
            model: "location"
        },` to user model?

Comment: Yes, but, what i need to write in controller? the model is ok, but the controller no.

Comment: Then once you `populateAll` or `populate('locationId')`, the outputted users would also contain location. Here in this case like this: `users[0].locationId`

Comment: Wow, this work, thanks , u are a master of sails :D .
 sorry my bad english.